# Problem with Drag-Drop from NSTableView to Finder

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, macos, drag-and-drop

I've created an app that has a NSTableView which represents a series of files. From this, I want to be able to drag a row (i.e. a filename) from my NSTableView to Finder, and the file be created in that folder.  However, the bit I can't work out is that I need to modify the contents of the original file, before it gets copied to Finder.

I've added the following line so I can drag outside of my NSTableView:

```
[self.tableView setDraggingSourceOperationMask:NSDragOperationCopy forLocal:NO];
```

And I can get it to copy the actual file, provided I add a current files location to the pasteboard, using:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard {
    [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObject:NSFilenamesPboardType] owner:nil];        
    NSMutableArray* dragfiles = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
    NSString* file = [self.files objectAtIndex:row];
    NSString* filepath = [[[self.pathControl URL] path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    [dragfiles addObject:filepath];
    [pboard setPropertyList:dragfiles forType: NSFilenamesPboardType];
    [dragfiles release];
}
```

But, because I want to modify the contents of the file, I don't want to put filepaths onto the pasteboard.  I've tried using NSFileWrapper, but Finder doesnt seem to accept this as a valid format.

I've checked Google, and I've found several suggestions that you can create a temporary file and use that filepath.  But, this feels ugly.

Is it possible to send data to Finder?  Is there a way to solve this?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You will most likely want to use promise files, or [`NSFilesPromisePboardType`](http://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/DragandDrop/Tasks/DraggingFiles.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/20001288-102943) rather than `NSFilenamesPboardType`. (Note: the promise file methods `dragPromisedFilesOfTypes:fromRect:source:slideBack:event:` and `namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:` that that documentation talks about are the generic `NSView` methods. `NSTableView` defines more convenient methods that you'll use instead of the generic ones. That said, that should still provide info on how promise file drags work). `NSTableView` uses `tableView:namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:forDraggedRowsWithIndexes:`, which is where you can do the processing of your files. In your `tableView:writeRowsWithIndexes:toPasteboard:` method, you'll declare `NSFilesPromisePboardType`, then set an array of filename extensions for the types of files you plan to write. The following is pseudo-code that outlines how you might approach it:

```
- (BOOL)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
     writeRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)rowIndexes
        toPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pboard {
     [pboard declareTypes:[NSArray arrayWithObjects:NSFilesPromisePboardType, nil]];

     NSMutableArray *filenameExtensions = [NSMutableArray array];
     NSArray *draggedFilenames = [self.files objectsAtIndexes:rowIndexes];
     for (NSString *filename in draggedFilenames) {
          NSString *filenameExtension = [filename pathExtension];
          if (filenameExtension.length) {
              [filenameExtensions addObject:filenameExtension];
          }
     }
     [pboard setPropertyList:filenameExtensions
                 forType:NSFilesPromisePboardType];
     return YES;
}
```

Then in your names-of-promisedFiles method:

```
- (NSArray *)tableView:(NSTableView *)aTableView
       namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:(NSURL *)dropDestination
       forDraggedRowsWithIndexes:(NSIndexSet *)indexSet {

     NSArray *draggedFilenames = [self.files objectsAtIndexes:indexSet];

     for (NSString *filename in draggedFilenames) {
           // do your processing of files in here
          // if it may take a long time, you might need to do it on a background
          // thread

         NSString *fullPathToOriginal = nil;
          NSString *destPath =
         [[dropDestination path] stringByAppendingPathComponent:filename];


     }
     return draggedFilenames;
}
```

You should be able to calculate the original file path (not sure how you're determining it, so I left it `nil` in the code above) and the destination file path (using something like in the code above).

Comment: Awesome. Many many thanks. Had it working 5 mins after reading this (having spent 3 hours trying to get something working last night).  My mistake was missing the relevance of the file extensions for the initial promise.  Thanks again.

Answer (score 6):

Something to watch out for.

In `NSPasteboard.h` there is a comment that says:

```
/* Use of pboard types should be replaced with use of UTIs.  
   Pboard types will be deprecated in a future release. */
```

And after the `NSFilesPromisePboardType` definition says:

```
// Use (NSString *)kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise
```

I just spent a few hours banging my head against a brick wall because I was passing in `(NSString *)kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise` instead of `NSFilesPromisePboardType` in a few places.

It looks like they don't do quite the same thing. I couldn't work out why:

```
tableView:namesOfPromisedFilesDroppedAtDestination:forDraggedRowsWithIndexes
```

wasn't being called. When I switched back to `NSFilesPromisePboardType`,
suddenly it was called.

Comment: `NSFilesPromisePboardType` expects filename extensions; `kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise` expects file URLs; `kPasteboardTypeFilePromiseContent` (only mentioned in Pasteboard.h, AFAIK) expects UTIs. The last is the modern replacement for the first.

Comment: Thanks for these precious hints, but how do you provide the URLs to kPasteboardTypeFileURLPromise? NSURL is not a pasteboard type.