# NSOutlineView drag and drop item as file

Tags: objective-c, cocoa, drag-and-drop, nsdocument

I'm recently working on an project aimed to extract files from an rar archive. I use an NSOutlineView to present the content. In which every file and directory listed as an item of class Entry. I want to extract the files user draged to the destination folder in Finder. But I can't get it right, here's the related code in Entry:

```
- (NSArray<NSString *> *)writableTypesForPasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard {
    NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
    // I don't known how to put an file representation on the pasteboard, and I don't want to extract it yet until the user drops in an Finder view. So I returned an URL, but seems not working.
    NSArray *ourTypes = @[(NSString *)kUTTypeURL];
    return ourTypes;
}

- (NSPasteboardWritingOptions)writingOptionsForType:(NSString *)_type pasteboard:(NSPasteboard *)pasteboard {
    NSLog(@"%s", __func__);

    if ([_type isEqualToString:NSPasteboardTypeString]) {
        return NSPasteboardWritingPromised;
    }
    return 0;
}

- (id)pasteboardPropertyListForType:(NSString *)_type {
    NSLog(@"%s", __func__);
    if ([_type isEqualToString:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL]) {
        NSURL *url = [NSURL fileURLWithPath:path];
        return [url pasteboardPropertyListForType:(NSString *)kUTTypeURL];
    }
    if ([_type isEqualToString:NSPasteboardTypeString]) {
        return self.name;
    } else {
        return nil;
    }
}
```

Any information or feedback would be appreciated, thanks in advance.

Comment: Maybe this will help: [Problem with Drag-Drop from NSTableView to Finder](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6674552/problem-with-drag-drop-from-nstableview-to-finder)